# Autocompletition in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I want to have an autocompletition which would look like the one in the image, with blue background and x-s for deletion of the chosen items.

In the example, I wrote 'j' and two users with j in their names are listed in the dropdown. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: @AkhilSekharan Can you tell me more details?

Comment: Sure. Are you using jquery? what is your server side language

Comment: @AkhilSekharan Yes i use jquery and c# is my server side language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the jquery plugin that you are looking for

[click here to learn more..](http://textextjs.com/)

Comment: I get Uncaught TypeError: Property 'input' of object #<c> is not a function. How to configure this plugin to work?

Comment: Download the plugin required files http://bundlejs.com/alexgorbatchev/products/textext/1.3.1 and checkout the example provided on this homepage http://textextjs.com/

Comment: I can't download them, instead the browser opens another tab.

Comment: copy the script in your local file with .js extension and add it to your html page.

Comment: I did that with this script:
http://bundlejs.com/alexgorbatchev/products/textext/1.3.1?compress=false&bundles=autocomplete

and i get two errors Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'TextExtAutocomplete' of undefined bundle.js:22
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'textext'

Comment: I use autocomplete tags filter plugin

Comment: in your code you are not including the textextjs script or may be the script is not downloading to your page.checkout this example http://muraliprashanth.me/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/autocomplete.html  and view source to include those missing files in data.json replace your url from where do you get the json data

Comment: Now when I enter a letter Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://muraliprashanth.me/manual/examples/data.json?q=a
error a autocomplete.js:9
GET http://muraliprashanth.me/manual/examples/data.json?q= 404 (Not Found)

Comment: That was just an example you need to configure url : '/manual/examples/data.json'; in ajax call to retrieve your json data to filter and add tags dynamically.The example data your retrieve from ajax call should look like [
 "Basic",
 "Closure",
 "Cobol",
 "Delphi",
 "Erlang",
 "Fortran",
 "Go",
 "Groovy",
 "Haskel",
 "Java",
 "JavaScript",
 "OCAML",
 "PHP",
 "Perl",
 "Python",
 "Ruby",
 "Scala"
] just like an array of strings..

Comment: now checkout the example http://muraliprashanth.me/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/autocomplete.html

Comment: Can you see this? http://jsfiddle.net/LnMrq/1/

Now in the autocompletition I don't get basic, closure etc, but instead I get the letters: b, a, s...

Comment: Ok I fixed it, now the autocompletition list is good. But the search is only for the first character. If I enter 'a' only apple is shown, not 'bar'.

Comment: But the search is only for the first character. If I enter 'a' only apple is shown, not 'bar'. How to fix this?

Comment: could you please provide your json data

Comment: ["apple", "pie", "bar"] and I want when the user enters a letter, all the words which CONTAIN that letter to list, not just the words that BEGIN with that letter.

Comment: May be you need to change the script that actually searches for that particular string

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use jQuery UI. You have an [autocomplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) and you can customize the CSS as you wish. For selecting multiple items you can use [tagsinput plugin](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput).

Here is a sample code for tagsinput:

```
$('#emails').tagsInput({ 
    width: 'auto', defaultText: 'Add email', isEmail: true 
});
```

Comment: But there is no blue background and x icon for deleting the choices from the textbox.

Comment: That functionality can be accomplished using TagsInput jQuery plugin: http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/

Comment: Is there a way to make some of the items in the autocompletition bold?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax and may be jquery ui autocomplete widget for this:

Since you are using asp.net, you can first create something like a handler in your application.

**Sample Handler**

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="SimpleHandler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;                      

public class SimpleHandler : IHttpHandler {   
    UCA.Common.DataControl.DBUtility dbu = new UCA.Common.DataControl.MsSqlDbUtility();
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        if (context.Request.QueryString["query"] != null)
        {
            context.Response.Write("You asked for "+ context.Request.QueryString["query"]);
            return;
        }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The in your html page, use this as a base,

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="txtSearch"/>
            <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" onclick="getDetails(document.getElementById("txtSearch").value)" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
        <br>
        <div id="txtResult"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getDetails(keyword)
            {
                var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","simplehandler.ashx?query="+keyword,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But there is no blue background and x icon for deleting the choices from the textbox.

Comment: This sample code is only for ajax. Once you get the data from the server you can use this data to populate a custom widget, for example you could use http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple this